# Discord.js Uptime Command

Tags: discord.js

Writing a command in djs that should display my uptime. When i run it, it displays the total number of seconds, minutes, hours, etc, but it doesn't limit seconds and minutes to seconds, or hours to 24.

```
    const seconds = Math.floor(message.client.uptime / 1000);
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    const days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    if(command === "uptime") {
        message.channel.send(`The bot has been up for` + ` ` + `${days} days,` + ` ` + `${hours} hours,` + ` ` + `${minutes} minutes` + ` ` + `${seconds} seconds.`)
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would division limit numbers? 5678000 / 1000 will always give 5678. What you want to do is modulo (`%`) instead of division (`/`).

```
const seconds = message.client.uptime % 1000;
const minutes = Math.floor((message.client.uptime / 1000)) % 60;
const hours = Math.floor((message.client.uptime / (60 * 1000))) % 60;
const days = Math.floor(message.client.uptime / (60 * 1000 * 60 * 24));
if(command === "uptime") {
    message.channel.send(`The bot has been up for` + ` ` + `${days} days,` + ` ` + `${hours} hours,` + ` ` + `${minutes} minutes` + ` ` + `${seconds} seconds.`)
    return;
}
```

There is a *better* solution, though. Convert number to Date format, and use it to directly get minutes, hours, days, etc. - the only downside of it is it gives day of the month, not the days passed since JS Epoch time, hence (unless there is an even cleaner solution I am not aware of) you need to initialize one more variable.

Also, why concatenate strings, if you can simply pass a single string with params?

*Anyway*, here is my solution to your problem:

```
var uptime = new Date(message.client.uptime);
const days = Math.floor(message.client.uptime / (60 * 1000 * 60 * 24));
if(command === "uptime") {
        message.channel.send(`The bot has been up for ${days} days, ${uptime.getHours()} hours, ${uptime.getMinutes()} minutes ${uptime.getSeconds()} seconds.`)
        return;
    }
```